# 'rogue' div is offsetting its siblings

Tags: html, css, layout

Basically I have a set of divs that are pretty much identical in structure, then following them I have a div that is unique to the set. Basically the first divs are a bunch of different categories and the last div is a userprofile type square. What I can't figure out is why the user profile square is being rendered with a higher position than the other divs.

they all have the same css

```
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px 10px 5px;
  width: 219px;
  height: 219px;
  background: #fff;
```

and the container has this css

```
display: block;
float: left;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding: 15px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-o-box-sizing: border-box;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
```

this is what it looks like
[image]

I'm guessing it's because the divs internal structure is different, but I'm not sure why it's doing this. I also noticed that if for example one of the category divs' images do not load it behaves the same way as my rogue div.

Any light there is to be shed on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: I think we need to see some live code to answer this, as I can't see anything in the code you posted which would cause it.

Comment: I agree with @NicoBurns, though a first wild guess would be that it's caused by the difference inline-block vs. block. Inline-block elements flow like inline elements (i.e. they align on text baseline by default), block elements align to the top of their parent, minus margin/padding.

Comment: Again, code would be best (even if it's a pain to do). Did you try making the other <div> an inline-block as well?

Comment: Here's a curiosity, when I change the rogue div to float rather than be inline it vertically aligns correctly, however it's obviously no longer part of the regular flow.

Comment: making the container an inline-block? all of the "squares" have an inline-block declaration.

Comment: My previous comment was a bit too quick, but again: you'll have to post more code, impossible to answer your question with the code at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `display: inline-block;` it's best to always add `vertical-align: top;` to the children (and then format from there as needed), especially if you have different element types or images in your container. Even images *inside* of your child elements can mess up the layout of `inline-block;`. `inline-block` elements also suffer from the "whitespace problem", which can affect layout. To prevent that you can either put all child elements together or comment out the whitespace.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/wwwkJ/

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="child">one</div>
    <div class="child">two</div>
    <img class="child" />
</div>

<div id="container-align">
    <div class="child-align">one</div>
    <div class="child-align">two</div>
    <img class="child-align" />
</div>

<div id="container-align-whitespace">
       <div class="child-align">one</div><!--
    --><div class="child-align">two</div><!--
    --><img class="child-align" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.child {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}

.child-align {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
}

#container, #container-align, #container-align-whitespace {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Output:

[image]