# Background image repeating even with 'background-repeat: no-repeat'

Tags: html, css

I can't stop the image repetition in my `td` elements. It looks very ugly. How do I solve this? I've added `background-repeat: no-repeat` code also, but it's still not working. Please don't suggest removing the `%` from the width of my `td`.

[image]

```
<table bgcolor="#d0e9ff" width= "100%">
 <td width="9%" height="40" background="images/button.jpg" background-repeat: no-repeat>
     <div align="center" border="0"><font face="arial, verdana, san-serif" size="2" ><a href="index.html " style="text-decoration:none"> 
     <font color="#ffffff"><b>Home</a></font></div>
  </td>

  <td width="9%" height="40" background="images/button.jpg" background-repeat: no-repeat>
     <div align="center"><font face="arial, verdana, san-serif" size="2"><a href="aboutus.html" style="text-decoration:none">
     <font color="#ffffff"><b>About Us</a></font></div>
  </td>

  <td width="9%" height="40" background="images/button.jpg" background-repeat: no-repeat>
    <div align="center"><font face="arial, verdana, san-serif" size="2"><a href="T&C.html" style="text-decoration:none">
    <font color="#ffffff"><b>Training and Certifications</a></font></div>
  </td>

  <td width="9%" height="40" background="images/button.jpg" background-repeat: no-repeat>
     <div align="center"><font face="arial, verdana, san-serif" size="2"><a href="services.html" style="text-decoration:none">
     <font color="#ffffff"><b>Services</a></font></div>
   </td>

    <td width="9%" height="40" background="images/button.jpg" background-repeat: no-repeat>
     <div align="center"><font face="arial, verdana, san-serif" size="2"><a href="Contactus.html" style="text-decoration:none">
     <font color="#ffffff"><b>Contact Us</a></font></div>
   </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Does it behave the same way if you use valid html and css instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got plenty of answers telling you how to fix your repeating image problem, but in case you decide to use a CSS design, here is something to get you started. This will eliminate the need for an image. You'll use a lot less HTML and it's more configurable.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/fJEJf/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="a" href="index.html">Home</a></li><!--
    --><li><a class="a" href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li><!--
    --><li><a class="a" href="T&C.html">Training</a></li><!--
    --><li><a class="a" href="services.html">Services</a></li><!--
    --><li><a class="a" href="Contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```css
ul {
    background-color: #d0e9ff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;   
    padding: 4px;
    width: 19.5%;
}

a {
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 16px;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    font: bold 13px arial, verdana, san-serif;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just curious: Any reason for commenting out between the ending </li> and next beginning <li> tags?

Comment: @ArjanEinbu With `display: inline-block;` it's necessary to prevent whitespace between elements. More precise layout. I have a good example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597431/rogue-div-is-offsetting-its-siblings/8597597#8597597

Answer (score 6):

You must set the `background-repeat` property within a `style` attribute:

```
<td width="9%" height="40" background="images/button.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat">
    <div align="center"><font face="arial, verdana, san-serif" size="2"><a href="aboutus.html" style="text-decoration:none">
    <font color="#ffffff"><b>About Us</a></font></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me like a typo. Did you try replacing `background-repeat: no-repeat` by `style="background-repeat: no-repeat"` ?

**EDIT :** I saw your website, and the correct CSS is not only this.

You need to put an `id="menu"` in you `<table>` tag, and then put this somewhere in `head`

```
<style>
#menu td {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Also, as stated by other members, you better place image background in the css properties itself, (its own stylesheet actually) and not in HTML code.

Comment: <td width="9%" height="40" background="images/button.jpg" style="background-repeat: no-repeat>
No Use.

The Full site is indotechnde.com. Try this Site Code. Its a current site. I am just encountered errors. Creates is other.

Comment: You are welcome. After visiting you website, I think you still miss a `background-position` somewhere in your menu, good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
style="background: url('images/button.jpg') top left no-repeat;"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
     #img_center {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: round;
    }
   </style>
```

This worked for me